# Blank row / Data with YADCF datatable

Tags: datatables-1.10, yadcf

I am using YADCF Datatable with ASP:GridView. Everything including column level filter is working as expected when there is some data available into Datatable. But facing issue in below mentioned case -

1. GRIDVIEW without any data: Sometimes as per query, Oracle not returning any row.  In this case YADCF Script throwing error - "http://localhost:55947/Design/js/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js
   0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'sTableId' of undefined or null reference occurred"
2. We are using ROWSPAN to show custom message to user on Initial Load. Later on User can select a filter and populate Grid. Here is the code -

   ```
      If Year = "Select FY" Then

       gvCff.ShowFooter = False
       gvCff.DataSource = GetBlankTable()
       gvCff.DataBind()
       gvCff.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader

       Dim totalcolums As Integer = gvCff.Rows(0).Cells.Count
       gvCff.Rows(0).Cells.Clear()
       gvCff.Rows(0).Cells.Add(New TableCell())
       gvCff.Rows(0).Cells(0).ColumnSpan = totalcolums
       gvCff.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text = "Please select FY to view data or select Browse option to upload data. "
   ```

Here getting this error message -

"localhost:55947/Design/js/jquery.dataTables.10.min.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined or null reference"

After few Googling, I tried to Add Language Option in YADCF JS. But not able to fix.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#gvCff').dataTable({
            "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
        }).yadcf([
            { column_number: 1 },
            { column_number: 2 },
            { column_number: 3 }]);
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: as to the yadcf error, please provide  a link to a test page so I can see what exactly happening